# Sybase: How to string multiple T-SQL commands together

Tags: t-sql, sybase, sap-ase

I want to execute the following commands in a single DataAdapter command:

`SET ROWCOUNT 10; SELECT * FROM dbo.SYB_CO_COLOUR ;SET ROWCOUNT 0`

but this isn't accepted by my Sybase DB, not even in the Interactive SQL tools that ships with the DB.

I have not changed the command_delimiter from the semi-colon default so I am surprised that I get the error

`Incorrect Syntax near ';'`

What am I missing?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remove semicolon and seperate them by space like:

```
SET ROWCOUNT 10 SELECT * FROM dbo.SYB_CO_COLOUR SET ROWCOUNT 0
```

It outputs 10 rows and resets rowcount back.